# To add a heatmap layer to a map in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, heatmap, geomap

I want to create a heat map layer in the map but when I am new to this heat map layer

trying to explore the option whichever option is there in layer configuration but I am new to this heat map layer. when I made a heat map layer then its not reflecting on map

Comment: I would recommend to go through the [Heat map layer in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/heatmap-layer.html)

Comment: Thank you I have one more doubts  have kibana dashboard and i want to have embed then in my html file  when i am embeding then getitng this issue Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-P5polb1UreUSOe5V/Pv7tc+yeZuJXiOi/3fqhGsU7BE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.